# COUNTERSTRIKE GO community server list problem

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse

While browsing for games to play on the Community Servers section, I am experiencing a problem where my mouse pointer completely disappears, and the GUI for the server lists is very small, almost illegible.

Is there a way to get my mouse to work in this window, and to change the resolution of the GAME SERVER GUI?

[image]

As you can see there is no mouse here.

ATI Radeon HD 4850 on a quadcore Imac (Mavericks)
not sure about configuration.

The problem seems to be intermittent.

Comment: Do you think you could include a few more bits of information so that we can help you better, such as a screenshot and your monitor/graphics card specs and configuration?

Comment: OK will add info to post

Comment: Sometimes this happens to me and right click of the mouse sometimes brings it back.